# Retrieve good php value inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I dot see where is my error, `productId` is always undefined
I tried different way but I have always the same error
below my code

my php code

```
        $products_id = 10;

        while ($Qreviews->fetch()) {
          $reviews_id = $Qreviews->valueInt('reviews_id');
 $products_reviews_content .= '
<div class="moduleProductsInfoReviewCustomersNotice">
  this comment is use full ?
  <strong><span class="toggleButton yesButton" id="' . $uniqueId . '_yesButton" data-unique-id="' . $uniqueId . '" data-product-id="' . $products_id . '">Oui</span></strong>
  <span class="toggleValue yesValue">(0)</span>
  <strong><span class="toggleButton noButton" id="' . $uniqueId . '_noButton" data-unique-id="' . $uniqueId . '" data-product-id="' . $products_id . '">Non</span></strong>
  <span class="toggleValue noValue">(0)</span>
  <span class="thankYouMessage" style="display: none;">Merci</span>
</div>
';

          $products_reviews_content .= '<script defer src="voted_review.js"></script>' . "\n";
}
```

my javascript code

this is this line does not work very well and the data is undefined. it must be `10`.

`const productId = this.getAttribute('data-product-id');`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Check if the user has already voted or not
  function hasUserVoted(reviewId) {
    const votedReviews = getVotedReviews();
    return votedReviews.includes(reviewId);
  }

  // Get local voted review to take the id storage
  function getVotedReviews() {
    const votedReviews = localStorage.getItem('votedReviews');
    return votedReviews ? JSON.parse(votedReviews) : [];
  }

  // Save function
  function markReviewAsVoted(reviewId) {
    const votedReviews = getVotedReviews();
    if (!votedReviews.includes(reviewId)) {
      votedReviews.push(reviewId);
      localStorage.setItem('votedReviews', JSON.stringify(votedReviews));
    }
  }

  // Function to handle the button click for "Oui"
  // Function to handle the button click for "Oui"
  function handleButtonClickYes() {
    const reviewId = this.getAttribute('data-unique-id');
    const productId = this.getAttribute('data-product-id');

    if (productId) {
      if (!hasUserVoted(reviewId)) {
        const parentDiv = this.closest(".moduleProductsInfoReviewCustomersNotice");
        const noButton = parentDiv.querySelector(".noButton");
        const yesValue = parentDiv.querySelector(".yesValue");
        const noValue = parentDiv.querySelector(".noValue");
        const thankYouMessage = parentDiv.querySelector(".thankYouMessage");

        noButton.style.display = "none";
        noValue.style.display = "none";
        yesValue.style.display = "none";
        thankYouMessage.style.display = "inline";

        markReviewAsVoted(reviewId);

        // Make an AJAX call to save the vote to the server
        saveVoteToServer(reviewId, 1, productId);
      }
    } else {
      console.error("Product ID element not found.");
    }
  }

// Function to handle the button click for "Non"
  function handleButtonClickNo() {
    const reviewId = this.getAttribute('data-unique-id');
    const productId = this.getAttribute('data-product-id');

    if (productId) {
      if (!hasUserVoted(reviewId)) {
        const parentDiv = this.closest(".moduleProductsInfoReviewCustomersNotice");
        const yesButton = parentDiv.querySelector(".yesButton");
        const yesValue = parentDiv.querySelector(".yesValue");
        const noValue = parentDiv.querySelector(".noValue");
        const thankYouMessage = parentDiv.querySelector(".thankYouMessage");

        yesButton.style.display = "none";
        yesValue.style.display = "none";
        noValue.style.display = "none";
        thankYouMessage.style.display = "inline";

        markReviewAsVoted(reviewId);

        // Make an AJAX call to save the vote to the server
        saveVoteToServer(reviewId, 0, productId);
      }
    } else {
      console.error("Product ID element not found.");
    }
  }


  // Function to send an AJAX request to save the vote to the server
  function saveVoteToServer(reviewId, vote, productId) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", 'voted_review.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            // Handle the response from the server if needed
            console.log('Vote saved for review ' + reviewId + ': ' + vote + "&product_id=" + productId);
        }
    };
    xhr.send("reviewId=" + reviewId + "&vote=" + vote + "&product_id=" + productId);

  }

  // Select all elements with the uniqueId attribute
  const reviewButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-unique-id]'); // Update to 'data-unique-id'

  // Add event listeners to each button
  reviewButtons.forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
      const reviewId = this.getAttribute('data-unique-id'); // Update to 'data-unique-id'
      if (!hasUserVoted(reviewId)) {
        const parentDiv = this.closest(".moduleProductsInfoReviewCustomersNotice");
        const yesButton = parentDiv.querySelector(".yesButton");
        const noButton = parentDiv.querySelector(".noButton");
        const yesValue = parentDiv.querySelector(".yesValue");
        const noValue = parentDiv.querySelector(".noValue");
        const thankYouMessage = parentDiv.querySelector(".thankYouMessage");

        if (this === yesButton) {
          noButton.style.display = "none";
          noValue.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          yesButton.style.display = "none";
          yesValue.style.display = "none";
        }

        thankYouMessage.style.display = "inline";

        markReviewAsVoted(reviewId);

        // Make an AJAX call to save the vote to the server
        saveVoteToServer(reviewId, this === yesButton ? 1 : 0);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: How are you calling the `handleButtonClickXX()` functions?

Comment: I don't think you're using `this` correctly in `handleButtonClickNo()` (possibly elsewhere as well). What's it meant to refer to? Where is that function used?

Comment: I have 2 button, one for Yes and one for No, The button works very fine, but the data sent does not have the productId value

Comment: You haven't shown how you're connecting the buttons to the functions. You're probably doing it in a way that doesn't pass `this` as you expect.

Comment: It should work if you do something like `yesButton.addEventListener("click", handleButtonClickYes)`